# review MongoDB collection naming and structuring

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Here's an example of my first try to make a structure of my MongoDB collection.

http://pastebin.com/vDLxysCk

**Description** A user is able to create an account and make purchases to existing stores on the database, but is also able to open his own store.

However I still have a few questions:

1. Is MongoDB a suited database type for this kind of data?
2. Is the structure correctly? (embed & reference)
3. I see people advising to store as much data into one document, how do you give a name to them? Since these hold multiple resources.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid your question is too broad. Can you please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs?

Comment: @chridam Sure. I'll edit the question. Just didn't want to spam StackOverflow with too many separate questions at once!

Comment: Thanks for the update, I think you might find these blog posts useful in answering your questions: [**part 1**](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1), [**part 2**](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87892923503/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2) and [**part 3**](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/88473035333/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3).

Comment: @chridam This kinda answered my question. As I'm reading trough rapidly now I already got most of my answers.